# Regex make a match must end with a number

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that captures a certain word can have a certain number of spaces after it and have a number right after.

Example

Created 100 images

I tried

```
/(created\s*\d*)/
```

Which matches what I want but also matches

'Created  '

^No digits are after the word.

I want it to must include a digit as well

Comment: **[Regex Quantifier Cheatsheet](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#quantifiers)** and **[More Quantifier Cheatsheet](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#morequants)**. Also, see [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970).

Comment: What does `*` mean in regex?

Comment: "certain number of spaces after it" - spaces should definitely be there? then you should use `\s+`. Else `created100` will get matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `\d*` to `\d+`. `*` means zero or more, where `+` means one or more.

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/rK7wJ6/1)